# Remove credit card from google wallet, will it affect purchased apps?

Tags: google-play-store, google-wallet

I use my credit card to buy app on Google Play Store and now that I changed my credit card, I want to remove my credit card info from my account, but Google gives me this message:

> You are about to remove the following credit card:
>   Visa ending in xxxx
>
> The following orders will be affected by removing this credit card:
>   [list of apps I purchased]

What happen when I remove my credit card, will I lose all my purchased apps? Or what will happen exactly?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes.

Your in-app subscriptions attached with that card will be disturbed. And, an app developer would be unable to refund money if you've purchased that app using that card (but, this is solved by contacting Google support).

But, you'll not lose any purchased apps. Even pending purchases will not be affected if you attach a new card with the account. Otherwise, it'd be cancelled.

Comment: Technically the first word should be "No" because the question is about purchased apps, not in-app purchases. Anyway, is there an official page about this?

Comment: @Richard More general answer is really more helpful here. Anyone is interested in paid features, not the paid apps. Plus, what I have wrote is my personal experience which can be verified easily. It should be on Google's support documentations, I think. I haven't searched there by the way.

Comment: *"Remove credit card from google wallet, will it affect **purchased** apps?"* "Yes." While it doesn't. It affects *future* purchases, and future **manual** refunds.

Comment: @RichardBorcsik "Remove credit card from google wallet, will it **affect** purchased apps?" "Yes." Where's the problem? Refunds fall in the *affect* category. And, just because OP did miss some details of his problem, I shouldn't drop in-app subscriptions.

Answer (score 6):

Of course not. The only way the would be affected is if they were still pending purchases. 
I have removed a card previously and all my apps were still intact.

Your purchases are linked to your account, not to your cards.
However common sense still applies. If you have in-app **subscriptions** set up on the card that you've removed, than the next charge will fail.

Comment: Because before I removed another card but had no such message, so that this time this confuses me.

Comment: @linkgreencold Just removed another cc to verify. Apps purchased can still be instaled, and show up in transaction history.

Answer (score 0):

Nope, The purchases generally go though, because your bank usually won't clear the funds till the next business day. I think Google simply gives that message for some legal reason.